# How to limit chrome extension to work only on a certain website

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm learning to build chrome extensions. I've build a simple hello world extension to test some chrome APis. I would ask if is possible to limit the extension only for a certain page, this because I don't want that the extension run on every website. Can someone point me into the right direction? I've searched a bit here on SO and I've found the page action api, but it's unclear to me how I can use it to achieve this scope. I know about content script but I don't want to inject anything inside the website, I just want to limit the extension execution.

For now I have this code in my manifest, and the icon will not be gray if I'm on the website where the extension can run, but the popup will not be opened

```
  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "__MSG_extName__",
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/19.png",
      "38": "icons/38.png"
    }
  }
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you don't expose a UI then you don't need a page_action or browser_action. Assuming your extension only uses webRequest, all you need to do is to add the URLs of the main site and the resources into manifest.json's `permissions`. It will make webRequest see only these URLs on this one site (additionally you can check `details.initiator` but in your case it might be an overkill).

Comment: @wOxxOm I never mentioned `webRequest`, maybe you are referring to the other question I've posted, but this is another project :). I just need to limit the extension only to a certain domain to let the icon and the popup available only for the declared website.

Comment: Well yeah you can use page_action for that, see and inspect the official [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: @alfaun0 This answer might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307355/10132227](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63307355/10132227)